# VMware workstation 12.1.1 updating kernal, services fail to start

Tags: linux, debian, vmware-workstation, kali-linux

I'm trying to setup VMware on Kali linux to make a tiny pentesting lab for learning. The first day it worked, then my OS broke after I think the upgrade,  I reinstalled the GUI and the files seem to be fine, I still don't know what happened. When I run it the kernal module tries to update, fails to start services, and then closes. I found a couple of old fixes for the same problem and none worked. A lot of the stuff mentions a version.h file that is a part of the linux headers package, it doesn't seem to be in the same place as the other posts about this. When I search for it this is what I see and I don't know which one is relevant.

```
root@kali:/# find . -name version.h*                                      
./var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.24/build/include/VBox/version.h
./usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/version.h
./usr/include/linux/dvb/version.h
./usr/include/linux/version.h
./usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-amd64/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
./usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-amd64/include/config/arch/want/compat/ipc/parse/version.h
./usr/src/linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common/include/xen/interface/version.h
./usr/src/linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common/include/uapi/linux/dvb/version.h
./usr/src/virtualbox-5.0.24/include/VBox/version.h
./usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include/xen/interface/version.h
./usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-kali1-common/include/uapi/linux/dvb/version.h
./usr/src/linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
./usr/src/linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64/include/config/arch/want/compat/ipc/parse/version.h
find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

I don't know what to do now. I'll toss this in and hope it helps in some way too.

```
root@kali:/# uname -rsv
Linux 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21)
```

Comment: This occurs when you try rebuild the modules against your new kernel? (the kernel moduls have to be rebuilt after every kernel upgrade) Do you have virtualbox and  vmware installed at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I just ran `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox` and `reboot` tried to run it same error still happens.

Comment: You can only have the kernel modules loaded of one or the other at one given time. Otherwise they mess each other up. Did you completley remove vbox then, all dependencies and configs? you'd do this with apt-get purge and apt-get auto remove. Do this for both virtualisers and reinstall the one you want

That is why I prefer kvm/libvirt based solution. Added bonus is that it is really open and free. No messing around with third party modules.

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling with uninstalling vmware, it's weird `sudo vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-player` I'm hoping this works, if it does thanks in advance, I'll try libvert.